# MySQL join four tables and get some kind of SUM result

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relationship

I have four tables like this:

```
mysql> describe courses;
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| course_id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| course_name     | varchar(75) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| course_price_id | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe pricegroups;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| price_id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| price_name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price_value | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe courseplans;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| plan_id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| plan_name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| plan_time  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe course_to_plan;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| course_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| plan_id   | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Let me try to explain what I have and what I would like to do... 
All my courses (`course_id`) has different steps (`plan_id`) wich has a value of 1 or more days (`plan_time`).
 A course has one or more steps (`course_to_plan`)
A course is connected to a pricegroup (`price_id`).
I would like to query my MySQL database and get an output off:
The `course_name`, the `plan_id`'s it has, and based on the value of `price_id` together with the value in the `plan_time` get a result who looks something like this:

```
+------------+--------------+------------+---------+
| course_name| pricegroup   | plan_time  | RESULT  | 
+------------+--------------+------------+---------+
| Math       | Expensive    | 7          | 3500    |
+------------+--------------+------------+---------+
```

I hope you understand me...
Is it even possible with the structure I have or should I "rebuild-and-redo-correct" something?

Comment: How is `RESULT` calculated?  Is it `price_value * plan_time` ?

Comment: result = price_value * plan_time?

Comment: For example: course X has three plans, wich has the values of `10`,`5`,`15` and it would be calculated with the `price_id` of wich the course is connected to. This can for example have the value `500`. My result for course X would then be `30 * 500 = 15000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.course_name, p.price_name, SUM(cp.plan_time), SUM(cp.plan_time * p.price_value)
FROM courses c
    INNER JOIN pricegroups p        ON p.price_id = c.course_price_id
    INNER JOIN course_to_plan cpl   ON cpl.course_id = c.course_id
    INNER JOIN courseplans cp       ON cp.plan_id = cpl.plan_id
GROUP BY c.course_name, p.price_name
```

Please note that it seems to me that your implementation might be erroneous. The way you want the data makes me think that you could be happier with a plan having a price, so you don't apply the same price for a plan which is "expensive" AND another plan which is "cheap", which is what you are doing at the moment. But I don't really know, this is intuitive :-)

Thanks for accepting the answer, regards.

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I understand what you need:

```
SELECT c.course_name, pg.price_name, 
       COUNT(cp.plan_time), SUM(pg.price_value * cp.plan_time) AS result
FROM courses c 
INNER JOIN pricegroups pg ON c.course_price_id = pg.price_id
INNER JOIN course_to_plan ctp ON c.course_id = ctp.course_id
INNER JOIN courseplans cp ON ctp.plan_id = cp.plan_id
GROUP BY c.couse_name, pg.price_name
```

Comment: honestly, that's why I said "lucky shot", it was just luck.. It could be COUNT also without any additional details :-)

Comment: You'r both awesome :) Thank's alot!